# How do I close a file in the terminal

Tags: python-3.x, file

I've only started doing python3 for a paper at university. I don't plan on continuing after this semester is over but I want to do the best I can in this class. However, I am having difficulties with seemingly a basic task.

I've opened a file using `f = open()` and I've accessed it in the terminal using less. It displays everything out nicely but it doesn't let me close the file or even continuing to code past the printed text.

It just repeats `~` on separate lines and finishes with a highlighted `(END)`

Comment: Can you try typing: `q` ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question on the Unix Stackexchange: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104499/how-to-exit-file-reading-mode-in-less-in-linux-terminal/104502

By the way, if you need help using `less`, hitting the `h` key will open the help page. It's really comprehensive and should help you out.

Comment: It's currently midnight here in New Zealand but I'll definitely try it in the morning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By typing `q`, you will be able to exit it

Comment: Thank you so much! I was getting so frustrated over it hahahah

Comment: Please consider accepting the answer if it helped you